# Adding firebase & emberfire dependencies to an ember.js app (ember-cli)

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit, emberfire, ember-cli

I'm an emberjs begginer and I have been searching how to add the "firebase" and "emberfire" dependencies to my ember application that I created using ember-cli. I used bower to install these 2 dependencies but I get this error:

```
    Firebase is not defined
ReferenceError: Firebase is not defined
    at eval (app/adapters/application.js:6:23)
    at requireModule (loader.js:54:29)
    at resolveOther (ember-resolver.js:158:20)
    at superWrapper (ember.js:1267:16)
    at Ember.DefaultResolver.extend.resolve (ember-resolver.js:205:17)
    at superWrapper [as resolve] (ember.js:1267:16)
    at Object.resolve [as resolver] (ember.js:41149:21)
    at Object.Container.resolve (ember.js:10907:29)
    at factoryFor (ember.js:11373:31)
    at instantiate (ember.js:11434:21)
```

here's my adapter:

```
    export default DS.FirebaseAdapter.extend({
    firebase: new Firebase('https://(myfirebaseurl).firebaseio.com')
  });
```

What should I do? I know I must have missed something, but I have already spent many hours and any answer given would be a great help ! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `bower install firebase`
2. Add `emberfire/dist/emberfire.min.js` to `Brocfile.js` inside the `legacyFilesToAppend` array.
3. Add a line in your bower.json file matching the version that you're using so that on a new checkout everything will continue to work.

*People visiting this in the future: this applies to ember-cli 0.0.21 ONLY.*

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example app by Stefan Penner https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli-ember-fire/

Comment: Note that Stefan's app is already out of date with the current version of ember-cli (only four days later). The only part of the *integration* in order to get emberfire included correctly is to add it to the `legacyFilesToAppend` array.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for this, I just created an `ember-cli` addon that include both firebase and emberfire into the app.

All you need to do is run `npm install --save-dev ember-cli-emberfire` from within your app and you should be good to go.

You can see the code here https://github.com/tikotzky/ember-cli-emberfire

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for help with this, I was able to get my app working by starting from scratch in a new branch and following these instructions: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/185#issuecomment-39170635