# Ember CLI - Firebase is not defined after installing with npm

Tags: ember.js, npm, firebase, ember-cli, emberfire

After taking the following steps in the command line to install Ember CLI, Firebase, and EmberFire with node, I am getting an error saying that Firebase is not defined in app/adapter/application.js

```
npm install -g ember-cli

npm install -g bower

npm install -g phantomjs

ember new my-new-app

cd my-new-app

ember server
```

At this point I can see my ember app with the default output of “Welcome to Ember.js” at localhost:4200

```
npm install firebase
npm install —save ember-fire
ember generate adapter application
```

Then in app/adapter/application.js, removed “export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({});” and pasted "export default DS.FirebaseAdapter.extend({
  firebase: new Firebase('https://.firebaseio.com')
});” with my own firebase URL

```
ember server
```

Then I get an error in terminal:

```
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200

lionworxs/adapters/application.js: line 4, col 17, 'Firebase' is not defined.

1 error

===== 1 JSHint Error

Path or pattern "vendor/firebase/firebase.js" did not match any files
Error: Path or pattern "vendor/firebase/firebase.js" did not match any files
```

I have tried creating the firebase.js file in the directory specified above, but it leads to an entirely new string of errors so I thought that I missed a step in my installation. Do I need to manually include Firebase somewhere in my application even after "installing" it via command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding firebase & emberfire dependencies to an ember.js app (ember-cli)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874575/adding-firebase-emberfire-dependencies-to-an-ember-js-app-ember-cli)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bower install Firebase and EmberFire.

```
    bower install firebase --save
    bower install emberfire --save
```

Be sure you've required the necessary script calls for Firebase and EmberFire in your index.html file:

```
    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.19/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- EmberFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/emberfire/1.1.3/emberfire.min.js"></script>
```

In your adapter, try using window.Firebase:

```
    import DS from 'ember-data';

    export default DS.FirebaseAdapter.extend({
      firebase: new window.Firebase('https://your-firebase-data-url.firebaseio.com/web/data')
    });
```

Your question is similar to this one - [Adding firebase & emberfire dependencies to an ember.js app (ember-cli)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874575/adding-firebase-emberfire-dependencies-to-an-ember-js-app-ember-cli) ...

And you might find the final comment there helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24541248/409156

Comment: I ran "bower install firebase", added the scripts to the head of my index.html file, and used window.Firebase rather than just Firebase in the adapter, and I now get a build error saying that "vendor/emberfire/dist/emberfire.js" did not match any files. I saw that post before but arrived at basically the same place I am now, any ideas?

Comment: bower install emberfire --save

Answer (score 0):

*I had the same issue as [user2817513](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2817513/user2817513). Copying this response from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874575/adding-firebase-emberfire-dependencies-to-an-ember-js-app-ember-cli) because it was the only thing that worked for me:*

Posted by [tikotzky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104376/tikotzky):

If anyone is still looking for this, I just created an ember-cli addon that include both firebase and emberfire into the app.

All you need to do is run npm install --save-dev ember-cli-emberfire from within your app and you should be good to go.

You can see the code here https://github.com/tikotzky/ember-cli-emberfire